How to initilize a class when the page is loaded. (ASP.Net Core (Razor Pages))
I am having an issue with my code where my OnGet() method isn't being called when the page loads. Now I may be wrong on how the OnGet() method is supposed to work but I cannot seem to figure out at bare minimum a work around. Here is my Index.cshtml.cs file:
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Dynamic;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor;
using SafetyApp.Services;

namespace SafetyApp.Pages
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly SafetyService _safety;

        public IndexModel(SafetyService safety)
        {
            _safety = safety;
        }
        public void OnGet()
        {
            var inspectionType = _safety.GetInspectionType();
        } 
    }
}

As you can see I have a constructor for the safety class and I set a variable equal to the result of that method. Thank-you for any insight on this problem I am having.

If it literally doesn’t get called, no errors or anything, chances are you’re missing the @model IndexModel directive in your Index.cshtml file.

Thanks, I had forgot I removed that earlier and never put it back.


How to initilize a class when the page is loaded. (ASP.Net Core (Razor
Pages))
I am having an issue with my code where my OnGet() method isn't being
called when the page loads. Now I may be wrong on how the OnGet()
method is supposed to work but I cannot seem to figure out at bare
minimum a work around. Here is my Index.cshtml.cs file.

Well, according to your shared code snippet and description it seems that you haven't call the OnGet in correct way, you should better share your view as well. Because its important how you are initializing your view so the OnGet.
However, I have investigate your code and based on your shared code snippet, you should have following code within your view in order to invoke your service method.
Demo Details of SafetyService:
Let's say, you have following details of SafetyService
public class SafetyService
{
    private readonly List<string> _inspectionTypes;

    public SafetyService()
    {
        _inspectionTypes = new List<string>
            {
                 //Demo Inspection type
                "Fire Safety Inspection",
                "Health and Safety Inspection",
                "Building Safety Inspection",
                "Electrical Safety Inspection",
                "Workplace Safety Inspection"
            };
    }

    public List<string> GetInspectionType()
    {
        
        return _inspectionTypes.ToList();
    }
}

IndexModel:
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly SafetyService _safety;

    public IndexModel(SafetyService safety)
    {
        _safety = safety;
    }

    public List<string> InspectionType { get; private set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        InspectionType = _safety.GetInspectionType();
    }
}

Note: As you notice I have introduced a variable InspectionType type of List<string> which I am going to use in view that would invoke the SafetyService and OnGet method.
View:
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}
<h1>Inspection Types</h1>
<ul>
    @foreach (var type in Model.InspectionType)
    {
        <li>@type</li>
    }
</ul>

Output:


Note: Please refer to this official document if you want to know more details, how should we initialize razor method in veiw or anything related to razor page.

I had forgot to add my model directive and that's where my issue was stemming from. Thanks for the help!
